# Statistical test for measure of association not assuming monotonicity in small samples (n=6)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, continuous-data

I have two continuous variables which I have data from a physics experiment.

I want to test for association between the two variables but without assuming a monotonic relationship. I also only have 6 data point each with a large error associated with it and want the test to take this into consideration.

Does anyone know of a statistical test of this type?

Comment: With only 6 data points, each with noise, no statistical test is going to give significant results and there will possibly be many shapes that fit.

Comment: If you had 6000 data points, identifying fairly general kinds of association should be possible. If you had 600 observations and made some weak-to-moderate assumptions about the general forms of association, you might get somewhere. If you had 60 observations and made fairly strong assumptions about particular forms of association it might be doable. On six observations with large error? I doubt there's any way you're going to achieve much; even something as explicit as monotonic association is going to be nigh impossible to show if the errors are large.

Comment: Josh, how many *free parameters* does the **physical theory** connected with your experiment have?

Answer (score 2):

Had you had a larger sample size, Hoeffding's D test is the most general one and is nonparametric.  It will even detect non one-to-one relationships (e.g., a circle).  This test is implemented in the R `Hmisc` package `hoeffd` function.

Answer (score -1):

If you focus mainly on the linear modeling approach, you can fit a smoothing spline with prespecified knots and polynomial degree. This has very robust properties and can estimate almost any type of trend consistently. Standard inference approaches are available to test whether the coefficients for this spline are all mutually zero, such as the likelihood ratio test. The limitation of this approach is that it can't detect differences in variances across groups. However, some post hoc testing using variograms and smoothing splines for squared residuals can determine this. I am usually only really interested in first-moment trends, and I think splines are very robust at estimating these (whether or not they're monotonic).

Comment: With only six data points, will there be any degrees of freedom left to conduct any effective test? And forget about variograms!

Comment: How did I miss that? Whoops, Josh you'll have to replicate your experiment a few thousand times, please!

Comment: By assuming linear dependence you have also missed the title, which is pretty clear that ANY relationship is assumed.

Comment: @Val you are confused what linear modeling is, a linear model is any model which allows you to write the expected value of the outcome as an explicit function of one or more terms of input variable, including polynomial transformations or, as I suggested, smoothing splines. Pick up "Elements of Statistical Learning" for distinctions on what constitutes and does not constitute a linear model.

Comment: @AdamO to be fair, "linear" has multiple meanings in statistical inference: (1) linear model, (2) linear functional relationship, (3) linear equations (the antonym being nonlinear and dynamic models).